# jQuery : map option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

I have a select list like this -

```
<select>
    <option value='A,textA$$B,textB' data-id='1'>some text</option>
    <option value='C,textC$$D,textD' data-id='2'>some text</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get this string as output -

```
1-1-A-textA,2-1-B-textB,3-2-C-textC,4-2-D-textD
```

- 1        - is just an index like 1,2,3,4..
- 1       - data-id
- A       - text before `,`
- textA   - text after `,`

Iv'e tried this (though, i know this is incomplete as i can't go beyond this)

```
var s = $('select option').map(function(){
   return this.value.split('$$').join(',');
}).get();
```

Fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/NgQzH/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't as simple as it seemed.  Once I realized the index incremented for each element, I had to create a wrapper function.  It is cool how map concats the arrays -- I did not know it did that.  Also this method has the added bonus of being able to correctly handle input values such as `C,textC$$D,textD$$E,textE`

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgQzH/5/)

```
function createArray() {
    var globalIndex = 1;
    var s = $('select option').map(function(index, elem){
        var ary = this.value.split('$$');
        for (i = 0, il = ary.length; i < il; i++) {
            ary[i] = (globalIndex++) + '-' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '-'
            +  ary[i].replace(',', '-');
        }
        return ary;

    }).get();
    return s.join();
}

console.log(createArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick and dirty fix to your fiddle

```
var s = $('select option').map(function(index, element){
       return (index+1) + "-" + $(element).data('id')  + "-" + this.value.split('$$').join('-').replace(/,/g,'-');
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NgQzH/4/

Comment: That returns an array of size 2, while i want it to be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var i=1;
var arr=new Array();
$('select option').each(function(index,value){
    f=$(this).val();
    fr=f.split('$$');
    fr1=fr[0].split(',');
    fr2=fr[1].split(',');
    j=1;
    arr.push(i+'-'+j+'-'+fr1[0]+'-'+fr1[1]);
    i++;j++;
    arr.push(i+'-'+j+'-'+fr2[0]+'-'+fr2[1]);
    i++;
});
console.log(arr.join(','));
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgQzH/6/)

**Updated**

```
var s='';
var i=1;
var j=1;
var arr=new Array();
$('select option').each(function(index,value){
    f=$(this).val();
    fr=f.split('$$');
    fr1=fr[0].split(',');
    fr2=fr[1].split(',');

    arr.push(i+'-'+j+'-'+fr1[0]+'-'+fr1[1]);
    i++;
    arr.push(i+'-'+j+'-'+fr2[0]+'-'+fr2[1]);
    i++;j++;
});
console.log(arr.join(','));
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/NgQzH/8/

Comment: this will output `1-1-A-textA,2-2-B-textB,3-1-C-textC,4-2-D-textD`